# While loop not stopping correctly

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a simple Fibonacci sequence program. My while loop doesn't stop correctly when the condition is met. For example, when num=10, my while loop doesn't end until counter===13. Am I misunderstanding something about while loops?

```js
let counter = 2; 
let sum = [1,1];
let i = 1;
let num = 10;

while(counter<num) {
   counter=sum[i-1]+sum[i];
   sum.push(counter);
   i++;
   console.log(counter + ' ' + num);
}
```

Comment: A loop will always exit when the condition is false. If it's not exiting, the condition is never false. Double check what `counter` is.

Comment: The loop condition is checked at the *beginning* of each iteration, not when the variable is assigned. Perhaps: `while(true) { counter=sum[i-1]+sum[i]; if (counter >= num) break /* stop loop "as soon as" counter >= 10, without adding counter to the results */; sum.push(counter); i++ }`.

Comment: 10 isn't a fibonacci number. Your counter is counting fib numbers, not iterations. On `counter === 8`, loop says, OK let's keep going because `8 < 10`. Next fib number is `8 + 5 = 13`, so `counter === 13` and loop stops because `13 > 10`.

Comment: Add some logging of the variables at relevant points so you can see where your (incorrect) assumptions do not match reality.

Comment: @user2864740 thank you so much! I had forgotten such a basic fundamental that the loop condition is checked at the beginning of the iteration. And thank you to everyone else for answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `counter` is actually changed only after the while condition is checked; so when it's equal to 8 (the sum of the last two values: 5 and 3), a last iteration can be performed, in which `counter` becomes 13 (8 + 5).

If you want to prevent it from exceeding 10, you can put the condition after the value modification and interrupt the loop if it's not met:

```
while(true) {
   counter=sum[i-1]+sum[i];
   if (counter >= 10) {
      break;
   }
   sum.push(counter);
   i++;
   console.log(counter + ' ' + num);
}
```

However, there are simpler ways to develop a Fibonacci series, such as recursive methods.

Answer (score 2):

Setting up a little test like this can be helpful to visualize what's going on.

```js
let counter = 2;
let sum = [1, 1];
let i = 1;
let num = 10;

while (counter < num) {
  counter = sum[i - 1] + sum[i];
  sum.push(counter);
  i++;
  console.log(
    `counter: ${counter}, i: ${i}, num: ${num}, sum: ${sum}, counter < num: ${
      counter < num
    }`
  );
}
```

If you do this, you'll see the following:

```
counter: 2, i: 2, num: 10, sum: 1,1,2, counter < num: true 
counter: 3, i: 3, num: 10, sum: 1,1,2,3, counter < num: true 
counter: 5, i: 4, num: 10, sum: 1,1,2,3,5, counter < num: true 
counter: 8, i: 5, num: 10, sum: 1,1,2,3,5,8, counter < num: true 
counter: 13, i: 6, num: 10, sum: 1,1,2,3,5,8,13, counter < num: false
```

The loop will exit when the condition is checked and the result is false. So, the counter will actually change *after* the last time the condition is true. When counter becomes equal to 13, the condition will no longer be true and after it is checked again, the loop will exit.